# Most straightforward way of inflating gzip memory stream

Tags: gzip, zlib

I have a gzipped file that I need to read and decompress in my application. I just read through the [zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html), and it appears that the `zlib` function are able to operate via memory buffers, but the `gzip` interface is all file-based.

What is the most common method of dealing with gzipped files like this? Do I need to handle the gzip file format myself, pull out the deflated data, and pass it to the zlib functions?

Note: The reason file-based will not work is because the file is in an archive on a read-only medium, so I can't extract the file first and use the gzip functions from zlib. This is an embedded Linux system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "read through" the zlib manual again, this time reading through it. `inflateInit2()` has an option to decompress gzip streams.

Comment: You're right, I missed that. I didn't completely read through it - I skipped the "advanced functions" section that it's in, thinking it wasn't a very advanced function I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: *That* Mark Adler :)  Thanks for taking time to point this out.